# Cordova/Phonegap upload image to amazon S3 through javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cordova, amazon-s3

Please help me on this one. I can't seem to find what the problem is. It looks like it goes all the way (fetching image, policy, signature etc.) until where it uploads the file. It does get rejected by Amazon... any idea why? Here's my upload code:

```
POLICY_JSON = { "expiration": "2020-08-06T12:00:00.000Z",
          "conditions": [
                         {"bucket": "gloportalmobile"},
                         {"acl": "public-read"}                   
                       ]
                     };
var policyEncBase64 = btoa(JSON.stringify(POLICY_JSON));
var secret = "--My--Secret--Key--Here--";
var encodedSignature = b64_hmac_sha1(secret, policyEncBase64);
b64_hmac_sha1(secret, policyEncBase64);
  var s3URI = encodeURI("https://gloportalmobile.s3.amazonaws.com/"),
      policyBase64 = policyEncBase64,
      signature = encodedSignature,
      awsKey = 'My--AWS--Key--here--',
      acl = "public-read";

function upload(imageURI, fileName) {


    var deferred = $.Deferred(),
        ft = new FileTransfer(),
        options = new FileUploadOptions();

    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = fileName;
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.params = {
        "key": fileName,
        "AWSAccessKeyId": awsKey,
        "acl": acl,
        "policy": policyBase64,
        "signature": signature
    };
    alert('encodedPolicy: '+policyBase64);
    alert('encodedSignature: '+signature);
    alert('imageURI '+imageURI);
    alert('s3URI '+s3URI);
    ft.upload(imageURI, s3URI,
        function (e) {
        alert('cool');
            deferred.resolve(e);
        },
        function (e) {
            alert('rejected');
            deferred.reject(e);             
        }, options);

    return deferred.promise();

}

return {
    upload: upload
}
```

So in those alert messages I can see the policy,signature,imageURI and S3URI with their values but is still throwing the alert "rejected" message.

Is this because my policy or signature is encoded wrong? or do i need to setup something on my gloportal bucket in Amazon S3 to accept it? Or some way amazon can tell me why they reject it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be options.headers instead of options.params